# causing unknowing harm to others

Tags: halacha, food

If I bought food in a store and it became unusable for any reason that is not noticeable and only applies to jews (e.g. food that was accidentally labeled as kosher but isn't) do I have to be concerned about returning/exchanging it in a store if a lot of other jews shop there?

Comment: A few aspects - 1) Most stores in the U.S. rarely reshelve food items, from what I've been told. I assume you're talking about non-perishable food that hasn't expired. They either go back to the supplier's inventory, or the store takes a loss (rare, but, some do this for customer relations.) 2) Is there actually a halachic concern with leaving a sealed can or package of food under your bed? Otherwise, what type of food are you referring to? 3) If a store DID reshelve it, offhand, I don't think that's your concern either way. You're not creating the problem by the store's decision to resehelve.

Comment: Re- my last item #3 - How would this be different from, say, your buying a knife from a store. You return the knife for exchange, and someone else buys the knife and uses it to murder someone. Are you responsible for the murder?

Comment: @danf 1)yes I was referring to non perishable items 2) if you look at the link I posted above yes there's a problem and 3) its not the same as the knife since here you know there's a possiblity of another jew doing something wrong when you could have prevented it

Comment: "2) if you look at the link I posted " - Was the link deleted? I don't see any link.